# How to amplify a differential signal

Tags: amplifier, signal, dac, gain

Let us say I have a DAC that gives out differential signal and I want to amplify it. How can I do that?

Comment: With 673 points, one should now how to ask questions here. Inserting your title into google results in the differential amplifier and instrumentation amplifier as possibilities.

Comment: THS4521 and similar. Actually... do you need single-ended or differential output?

Comment: *How can I do that?* You would use a **differential amplifier**, learn about those by putting that term into Google search and doing some studying.

Comment: What kind of output the amplifier should have? Single-ended or differential? Do you want a fully differential amplifier? What is the required bandwidth and dynamic range of the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a differential amplifire or a differential transformer.
Take a look at pg.4/pg.5 of [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-019.pdf) document.